# Hierarchical state machines for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, state-machine

Ive been super interested in hierarchical state machines particularly in JavaScript and I found [this](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine) framework and like how it's looks. However I'm not sure if it can perform hierarchical operations.

Does anybody know of solutions alreadyr out there're for hierarchy state machines?

Answer (score 4):

If you want something like the pattern described in [this article](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/hierarchicalstatemachine.htm), it looks like the framework you linked can do that:

> ### State Machine Classes
>
> You can also turn all instances of a class into an FSM by applying the state machine functionality to the prototype, including your callbacks in your prototype, and providing a startup event for use when constructing instances:

```
MyFSM = function() {    // my constructor function
  this.startup();
};

MyFSM.prototype = {

  onpanic: function(event, from, to) { alert('panic');        },
  onclear: function(event, from, to) { alert('all is clear'); },

  // my other prototype methods

};

StateMachine.create({
  target: MyFSM.prototype,
  events: [
    { name: 'startup', from: 'none',   to: 'green'  },
    { name: 'warn',    from: 'green',  to: 'yellow' },
    { name: 'panic',   from: 'yellow', to: 'red'    },
    { name: 'calm',    from: 'red',    to: 'yellow' },
    { name: 'clear',   from: 'yellow', to: 'green'  }
  ]});
```

> This should be easy to adjust to fit your appropriate mechanism for object construction.

In other words, at this point you should be able to do the usual JavaScript inheritance thing, something like:

```
function MyCalmFSM() {
    MyFSM.apply(this, arguments);
}

MyCalmFSM.prototype = Object.create(MyFSM.prototype);
MyCalmFSM.prototype.constructor = MyCalmFSM;

// Don't panic
MyCalmFSM.prototype.onpanic = function(event, from, to) { alert("Don't panic"); }
```

Comment: Do you think this would be easily implemented with knockoutjs view models?

Comment: @Ryan I haven't used that framework, but I took a quick look and I don't see why it wouldn't work. From what I can tell the view models are just plain old objects, so I guess you'd use these constructors to construct those objects and then hook them up to knockout.

Comment: I guess I don't see how this class integration results in a hierarchical fsm. There are rules that must be obeyed, that javascript isn't just going to do for you... has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at: https://github.com/steelbreeze/state.js

It supports hierarchies of alternating states (state, pseudo state & final state) and regions in a manner closely aligned to the UML 2.x spec.  It's early days for the project, but the basics are there.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but you could have a look to the iFSM library based on jQuery that can design HSM: https://github.com/intersel/iFSM